# Corroded Sink Drain Cover Removal Suggestions

Tags: faucet, pipe, sink

I've pretty much taken my entire old faucet apart except the last piece, the Sink Drain Cover.

[image]

I've put WD-40 on it, didn't help much. I've read about different products that help with corroded metal, but i'm assuming you have to actually apply them where the thread meets.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, was using a heavy duty pair of pliers to grasp on to the drain flange. Then another pair of hands, also using heavy duty pliers, turning the tail piece. I was originally trying to do this on my own, and couldn't grasp the drain and turn the tail piece at the same time.

Extra pair of hands did the trick. It's also possible that I needed to give the WD-40 time to work it's magic.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "mini-hack" saw, they work great for actually slicing the drain spud then grabbing it with Channellocks, crushing it, then pulling it out.

Or you could attack from below with a long-shank sacrificial slotted screwdriver and bust the corroded nut off by pounding the screwdriver with a hammer and using it like a chisel.

Brute force carefully applied will do the trick, I've done it many times.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reciprocating Saw should get it or even a Dremel or Grinder. If you want to twist the bottom nut off then you'll need either large Vise-Grips up top (so they twist & shoulder against the sidewall of the sink as you wrench below) or the long thin handles of a Channel-Lock plier to fit into the drain's bottom cross-member or "X" strainer.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this tool is made for just that purpose:

[image]

Basically, it's an easy-out for drain ends.

Here's a link to one on [Lowe's web site](http://www.lowes.com/pd_422163-943-05255.STC1_?productId=3817495), albeit a dead one, but it's where I bought mine.